# Can I upload 2 code files to a NodeMCU

Tags: smart-home, networking, arduino

I have a NodeMCU board. I uploaded blink example for that board and I need to add another example project from the IDE. What happens to the 1st code example or blink example when 2nd code uploaded. Is it being deleted or something else ?

Comment: yes .... deleted

Comment: It is deleted and replaced. If you want the NodeMCU to perform the tasks of two different projects you'll need to merge them at the source level, which may be very easy or extremely complex depending on what each does.